# Firebase remote config alternatives

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Are there some alternatives to Firebase Remote Config? 
I need to deliver an App for chinese market and I'm not sure that it will work

Comment: have you tried safeDk

Comment: If you are  simple set of key/value pairs that get pulled into your app you can try services that use Parse Server as back-end , something like back4app.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved with Parse https://parseplatform.org/
there's also a baas implementation provided by https://www.back4app.com/ with a free tier

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use Huawei Remote Configuration, it mostly matches Firebase for API style.

Sign up for the Huawei console https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/remote-configuration/

Add the dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-remoteconfig:1.5.2.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.0.0.300'
```

Fetch the same as Firebase Remote Config:

```
config = AGConnectConfig.getInstance()
config.fetch(0) // a value of 0 here is for DEBUGGING ONLY, delete for prod (giving a 12 hour refresh period)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        config.apply(it)
        Log.d(TAG, "Applied")
        //update based on RemoteConfig
    }
```

Reference: https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/remote-configuration-using-appgallery-connect/